# How to exchange context value between servers?

Tags: go

I'm studying Golang and have question on context.

I want to send request from server1 to server2 with context and want to read context value set by server1.
But it seems context of sercer2 doesn't carry server1's context value.

When I send request to server1 by curl http://localhost:8080

server1's console.

```
Send request to http://localhost:8082
```

server2's console.

```
request coming in
<nil>
```

How can I retrieve context value set by server1?

And if it is possible, I also want to know whether it is a correct way of exchanging value's like authentication between servers.
Middleware pattern is more desirable?

Thank you.

Codes

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", hello)

    fmt.Println("Starting listening on port 8080...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

// Context's key.
type Sample string

var sampleKey Sample = "sample"

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Println("Send request to http://localhost:8082")
    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), sampleKey, "1234")
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "http://localhost:8082", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while sending request: ", err)
    }

    // Send request.
    var c http.Client
    c.Do(req)
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/", receive)
    fmt.Println("Start listening on port 8082...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8082", r)
}

type Sample string

var sampleKey Sample

func receive(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("request coming in")
    fmt.Println(r.Context().Value(sampleKey))
}
```

Comment: Your servers communicate through HTTP. The `context.Context` type is a Go stdlib construct that is not part of HTTP, hence it doesn't get relayed. To send information from one server to another you can use an HTTP request's query parameters, or headers, or its body.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.
I understand and use query parameters.

Comment: You cannot and you should not. Try to understand the should not part.

Answer (score 0):

The `context` is supposed to be used in a function call stack to share information and cancellation point between these functions. There is no automatic mechanism to serialize the value bound in the context over http. If you want to send data over http between these two servers, you mostly have three solution, you can:

- encode that as an url parameter in the path somewhere

  ```
  GET /hello/1234
  ```
- send that in the http body, for example in JSON

  ```
  POST /hello

  {
     "sample": 1234
  }
  ```
- as url key/value encoded as url parameters

  ```
  /hello?sample=1234
  ```

Comment: Thank you davidriod for your helpful and clear explanation. I'm gonna try to use url parameter way.